# Controlling an AC motor

Tags: arduino, motor, control

I want to build an electric bike and i need some sort of control over the motor ( i want to build it myself):
It doesn t have to be a throttle-like control (as the ones on actual motorcycles), it just has to control the speed of the motor. What is the best way to do so? Would a transistor be ok (1kw - maximmum power of the motor that i will chose - 220vAC)?
I can use an Arduino to control it. Is there a better alternative to this ?

Comment: I think you have oversimplified the problem.

Comment: I am new to AC motors... could you explain?

Comment: How exactly are you powering your *AC* motor?

Comment: Either with a 12v battery+1kw inverter or petrol powered electricity generator